# Is there a way to compare file history with the current HEAD using GitLens?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlens

I am using GitLens file history in VSCode to view older file commits. When I click on a file, I get a comparison between the commit I clicked and the immediate predecessor commit. Whilst this is useful in specific use cases, for me being able to click a files historical commit and compare it to the current HEAD is far more valuable. Is there a way to make this the default behaviour?

I can open the comparison tab and split it, and then open the current file (which means there are a total of 3 tabs open), but this is not optimal.

Comment: next to the file name: I have a `[...]` button, when clicking on it I get a list of actions including "Compare with HEAD"